# Trying to load SFML sprites into array, then access attributes of each?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++17

I've been learning c++ through a book I recently bought by John Horton that teaches you via game creation. It briefly mentions placing SFML sprites into an array that can then be accessed later, but doesn't cover it much. I've been trying to figure it out myself, but the SFML documentation doesn't really clarify it entirely for me (or I just don't understand it correctly yet). Anyway, this is what I'm trying, but I get the error "expression must have handle or pointer" for `clouds[i]` in the cout line.

I'm trying to make it so I can use this function to retrieve the positions of each cloud and, if needed, be able to change it. I thought I needed a reference or pointer but neither are working.

```
int GetClouds()
{
    Texture textureCloud;
    textureCloud.loadFromFile("graphics/cloud.png");
    Sprite spriteCloud;
    spriteCloud.setTexture(textureCloud);

    Sprite clouds[3];
    for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      clouds[i] = spriteCloud;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i != 2; i++)
    {
        std::cout << clouds[i]->getPosition;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `clouds[i]->` to `clouds[i].`

Comment: Probably should be something like `std::cout << "[" << clouds[i].getPosition().x << ", " << clouds[i].getPosition().y << "]\n";`.

Comment: @AmirKirsh when I do that I get  `sf::Transformable::getPosition': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`

Comment: @George Oh, I didn't even think of that! That absolutely works, thank you so much. Sorry if the question seems simple.

Comment: Have a look at [Heap vs Stack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-vs-heap-memory-allocation/#:~:text=In%20a%20stack%2C%20the%20allocation,in%20heap%20memory%20is%20fragmentation.)